# Not able to download file from HttpMessageResponse return type API

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I have the following code for controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Download")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetBookForHRM(string id)
{
    string filePath = "path/to/your/file.txt";

    var dataBytes = FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);

    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");

    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = bookName;
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    return httpResponseMessage;
}
```

The code is supposed to download file when API method is called, but it is returning JSON as response. No file is being downloaded

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try...

```
    [Route("Download")]
    public IActionResult GetBookForHRM(string id)
    {
        ...

        return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", bookName);
    }
```